# Apllication Error 1000 SearchProtocolHost.exe

Tags: outlook

При подключении PST файла через некоторое время, при попытке просмотра содержимого PST файла, вот такая картина (см. ниже)

В логах:

Имя сбойного приложения: SearchProtocolHost.exe, версия: 7.0.7601.17610, отметка времени: 0x4dc0c63a
Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия: 6.1.7601.18409, отметка времени 0x531599f6
Код исключения: 0x80000003
Смещение ошибки: 0x0003492e
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x17d0
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d10d56ee17b8ea
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Windows\system32\SearchProtocolHost.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Код отчета: 9197a296-794a-11e5-ab65-6cf04917e351

Затем

Имя сбойного приложения: SearchProtocolHost.exe, версия: 7.0.7601.17610, отметка времени: 0x4dc0c63a
Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия: 6.1.7601.18409, отметка времени 0x531599f6
Код исключения: 0x80000003
Смещение ошибки: 0x0003492e
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x1740
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d10d57559e0ee6
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Windows\system32\SearchProtocolHost.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Код отчета: 93f98706-794a-11e5-ab65-6cf04917e351

И наконец

Не удается завершить индексирование данных Outlook. Невозможно продолжить индексирование для <вырезано> (ошибка=0x8034081f). Если ошибка повторится, обратитесь в службу поддержки корпорации Майкрософт.

Пробовал:

1. Подключить на другом ПК с Win8 и такой же версией офиса - нет проблем
2. Восстановить компоненты Microsoft Office 2013
3. Поставить последние обновления для Microsoft Office 2013

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: IMHO, в Microsoft, как и написано в сообщениях об ошибке. Гадать по столь скудным данным в столь большом и сложном приложении - крайне неблагодарное занятие...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена исключением файлов Outlook из индексирования.